# SVN client with higher rev than server

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Due to a human error, we had to restore svn data on server from a backup. The backup is 1 day old.

What happens when someone commits with a higher rev number than the server version? How should we mediate this problem?

Comment: Do an update for all your users and be happy

Comment: @Y.N: No, that will not work. See my answer.

Comment: @sleske - Yes, I was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tested this with a local repository. I created a repository with a few commits, created a backup copy of the repository folder, added another commit, then replaced the repository folder with the old backup copy.

After restoring the repository to its old state (with an old revision), the behaviour is as follows:

- Working copies with a newer revision will no longer be able to run `svn update` or `svn log`. They will get an error message: "svn: E160006: No such revision xxx".
- However, the working copies *will* be able to send a new commit. The server will assign the commit the next SVN revision from its point of view - however, other working copies will not fetch this commit with `svn up`, since they already have a (different) commit with that revison number. Hence, working copies will diverge.

**TL;DR:**

This is *not supported* by Subversion. All existing working copies must be discarded (and checked out anew).

If working copies have uncommitted changes, these should be saved (e.g. using `svn diff` - but beware of limitations such as moved files) and re-applied to the fresh checkout.

Comment: That's what basically happened to us as well. Had to merge old working copy (with higher rev) to fresh working copy and commit. As you'd imagine, people were not happy about it.